# How to erase SQL queries from ActiveRecord::Base.logger

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm developing an application using Ruby on Rails.

I would like to erase old queries in the ActiveRecord::Base.logger object every time when I call a new action, essentially where ENV = production.

The goal is not to erase all queries like using config.log_level :info. I need only last queries to build a file with those queries.

Here is some code:

in the lib:

```
module SqlHunter
  class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractAdapter
      @@queries = [] # without this line it work perfectly
      @@logging = false
      cattr_accessor :queries, :logging
      def log_info_with_trace(sql, name, runtime) 
        @@queries << sql if @@logging 
      end
      alias_method_chain :log_info, :trace
  end
end
```

in the controller (report action)

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractAdapter::logging = true
```

.....

```
sqlfile = File.open("public/advancedStats/#{@dir_name}/advancedStatQuery.sql", 'w')
@queries = ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractAdapter::queries
for query in @queries do
   sqlfile.write("#{query} \n")
end
sqlfile.close
```

I asked an old related question here

[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701236/how-to-get-sql-queries-for-each-user-where-env-is-production)

Thanks to Tamás Mezei and Damien MATHIEU for their last answer

Mondher

Comment: If you are running a high traffic site or on a constrained environment, try to replace that logging function with something less resource-consuming. Constantly opening and closing a file is definitely not a good idea, maybe sending those logs to a queue and defer writing will support you better.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to filter the SQL queries in production mode or am I missing the point?

If it's about just filtering, prod mode will automatically filter sql queries. If you'd like to filter when developing, edit the **config/environments/development.rb** file and insert

```
config.log_level = :info
```

Essentially, it will filter SQL with all the other stuff that's below info level (debug stuff).

If you want some more sophisticated solution, you can always exend/override the **AbstractAdapter** class in

```
RUBY_HOME/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-nnn/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb
```

Comment: Hi Tamas,
Thanks for your answer, but i don't like to erase all queries.

I reeditted my question and you can have more idea

Mondher